# AspectJ won't run

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop

So, i have started learning spring boot and i came across AOP.

I made myself an aspect which looks something like this

```
@Aspect
public class Logging {
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.tilak.*.*(..))")
    private void selectAll(){}


    @Before("selectAll()")
    private void beforeAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Going to set up student profile");
    }

    @After("selectAll()")
    private void afterAdvice(){
        System.out.println("student profile has been set.");
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "selectAll()" , returning = "retVal")
    private void afterReturningAdvice(Object retVal){
        System.out.println("Returning: "+   retVal.toString());
    }


    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "selectAll()" , throwing = "ex")
    private void afterThrowingAdvice(IllegalArgumentException ex){
        System.out.println("There has been an exception: " + ex.toString());
    }

}
```

I have one more class *Student* which looks like this

```
@Component
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String game;


    public Integer getAge() {
        System.out.println("Age : " + age );
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGame() {
        System.out.println("Name : " + game);
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(String game) {
        this.game = game;
    }


    public void printThrowException(){
        System.out.println("Exception raised");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Main Class looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String... z) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, z);

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanMe.class);
        Student student = (Student) applicationContext.getBean("student");



        student.getAge();
        student.getGame();
        student.printThrowException();

    }
}
```

Bean class looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class BeanMe {
    @Bean(name = "student")
    public Student studentBean(){
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setAge(24);
        student.setGame("Tilak raj");
        return student;
    }


    @Bean("logging")
    public Logging loggingBean(){
        return new Logging();
    }
}
```

Pom file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springbootexample</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstspringboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <game>firstspringboot</game>
    <description>Practise project for spring boot
    </description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My output:

> Age : 24 
>   Name : Tilak raj 
>   Exception raised Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   com.tilak.aop.Student.printThrowException(Student.java:33)    at
>   com.tilak.aop.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:24)

I think i have included every dependency needed to make this run but i am not getting the expected output.

The Advices should run but they are not. What am i missing here?

Update:

[image]

Comment: @EnableAspectJAutoProxy ?

Comment: @SachinVerma where should i put it ?

Comment: add @Configuration to Aspect class, and please, make all aspects methods public. You could made pointcuts private but not the aspects, aspects should be public

Comment: @EgorKravchenko did it , still same errir

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace, this appears to be only a snippet. `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` isn't needed as that is automatically applied by Spring Boot.

Comment: What packages are your classes in...

Comment: @M.Deinum package com.tilak.aop;

Comment: Are **all** your classes in that package?

Comment: Yes. all my classes are in that package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179376/discussion-between-botjr-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Then your point cut is wrong as well. `com.tilak.*.*(..)` matches all class and methods in the `com.tilak` package. It doesn't match all classes in other packages. The first `.*` is all -classes in package, the second `.*` is all methods. You want the first `.*` to be `..*` (notice the `..`) which also includes sub packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in the `main` method is doing the wrong things. The `SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, z);` already returns an `ApplicationContext` you are constructing it again and only with a part of your configuration. The missing part is the fact that this doesn't have aspectj enabled.

However as you are re-loading an already loaded context don't do that, use Spring Boot in a proper way.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String... z) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, z);
        Student student = ctx.getBean("student", Student.class);

        student.getAge();
        student.getGame();
        student.printThrowException();
    }
}
```

This will load the application, retrieve the bean and call the methods.

Next to that your pointcut expression is also wrong. `execution(* com.tilak.*.*(..))` means the exception of all methods for classes in the `com.tilak` package. As your classes are in the `com.tilak.aop` package that doesn't match.

Use either `` execution(* com.tilak..*.*(..))` or ``execution(* com.tilak.aop.*.*(..))`either will work. The first includes sub packages due to the`..` the other one uses the full package.

However doing so will result in another issue, the aspect will create apply to itself as well (you will notice this when starting the application). So you want to limit it either to the `Student` class or exclude classes annotated with `@Aspect`.

To test you can use `execution(* com.tilak.aop.Student.*(..))` as the pointcut as that will match only the `Student` class and not the aspect.

Comment: You are forcing the error yourself... You should still see the Aspects being invoked this way. If it isn't than the code you posted isn't the code you are actually using.

Comment: I have pasted out everything that i have

Comment: Two more things i would like to mention, i didn't have configuration annotation on the logging aspect plus i was making a bean in the mybean class too.

I removed the bean from the my bean class. I added an configuration annotation on the Logging class.

This pointcut thing was the error too. Now it's working.

Comment: Don't add `@Configuration` to the aspect. It isn't configuration, if anything it is a component.

Comment: Okayy.Thank you. Is there any good ssource for spring boot? All i seeing is some complicated stuff.